# No he podido usar fullcalendar en laravel

Tags: php, fullcalendar, laravel-6

"Estoy realizando una pagina web con laravel y para eso necesito usar fullcalendar, sin embargo no he podido usarlo dentro mi aplicación debido a que cuando abro la pagina en el navegador no me aparece nada. He seguido los pasos que aparecen dentro de la documentacion oficial y a pesar de eso no he logrado solucionar el problema"

"Este es mi codigo:"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />

    <link href='..\fullcalendar\packages\core\main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='..\fullcalendar\packages\daygrid\main.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <script src='..\fullcalendar\packages\core\main.js'></script>
    <script src='..\fullcalendar\packages\daygrid\main.js'></script>

    <script>

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ]
        });

        calendar.render();
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

error:[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

segun veo ese es tu codigo que usarias en una aplicacion html sencilla y debe funcionar, pero en laravel es un poquito diferente en como lo configuras, tienes algo hecho en laravel?, quizas si sigues estos videos te ayuden:
[Fullcalendar 4 con laravel 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNyhlFALd6I&list=PLSuKjujFoGJ3yVQMps4A24g3eBSkUCLXZ&index=14)